# Diferencia entre el empeine, la región plantar y el arco plantar

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico

He encontrado esas tres palabras en mi diccionario visual, pero las líneas que conectan las palabras a las imágenes no están claras.

La traducción al inglés para las palabras son (según mi diccionario visual):

- **la región planta**r = instep (la parte baja de la imagen del pie)
- **el arco plantar** = arch (la parte baja de la imagen del pie) el
- **el empeine** = bridge (la parte alta de la imagen del pie)

No he encontrado ninguna pagina en español sobre la diferencia entre las palabras españolas. Aunque, he encontrado [esa pagina](http://www.dance.net/topic/7971307/1/Ballet-General/What-s-the-difference-between-your-arch-and-your-instep.html&replies=4) que dice que la región plantar (instep) es la parte superior del pie y el arco plantar (arch) es la parte inferior del pie. Yo creería que la región plantar tiene que ser en la planta también :)

Otro diccionario me confundió aún más. [Ese](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/empeine) dice que el empeine es instep en inglés. Tiene sentido si consideramos la respuesta en la otra pagina pero entonces la traducción en mi diccionario visual no está correcta.

Pueden ayudar con la traducción al inglés y la parte del pie a que se refieren las palabras?

Gracias,
Norbert

Comment: You might want to look at the Wikipedia entry for Pie https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie which tells you more, much more, about the foot than you could possibly dream of.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The wikipedia page only mentions "empeine" and "arco plantar" as a label to two images. It does say that "empeine" is the top part of the foot which coincides with where the line points to in the dictionary. The translations are not given, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El empeine es la parte superior del pie (que abarca desde los dedos hasta el tobillo), y su traducción al inglés sería *instep*.
Por su parte, la región plantar es lo conocido como la "planta del pie", y sería toda la parte inferior del pie, excluyendo los dedos y el talón. La traducción más correcta sería *sole*.
Y el arco plantar sería (nunca mejor dicho) la parte del pie más interna, que en mayor o menor medida forma un arco. Ten en cuenta que éste forma parte de la planta del pie. Su traducción sería *arch of the foot*.
If you have any further questions, or want me to clarify anything, just ask